# How to avoid writing the same logic in components having a different layout?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router, react-redux

How can I avoid writing the same code when two components share some same methods but have a different layout?

The sample components below have a method "renderLastItem" which uses prop "something" passed by the parent components.

I thought about using Higher Order Component Pattern but I'm not sure I I can pass props as an argument to Higher Order Component.

The sample code below is very simple, so in this sample code, I just need to use If statement and change the layout according to the type of components, but in real code, I have more codes and I want to avoid using if statement in order to change the layout according to the type of a component.

How can I avoid writing the same logic in multiple components?

## ComponentA

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const propTypes = {};
const defaultProps = {};

class SampleA extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    renderLastItem() {

        if(!this.props.something) {
            return  null;
        }

        return this.props.something[this.props.something.length - 1];

    }


    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <h1>Something</h1>
                <p>{this.renderLastItem()}</p>
            </div>

        );

    }
}

SampleA.propTypes = propTypes;
SampleA.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default SampleA;
```

## ComponentB

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const propTypes = {};
const defaultProps = {};

class SampleB extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    renderLastItem() {

        if(!this.props.something) {
            return  null;
        }

        return this.props.something[this.props.something.length - 1];

    }


    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Something</li>
                    <li>Something else</li>
                    <li>{this.renderLastItem()}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        );

    }
}

SampleB.propTypes = propTypes;
SampleB.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default SampleB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can pass props to a Higher-Order Component! A HOC is simply a function that takes a Component as an argument and returns another Component as a result. So you could create a Higher-Order `withLastOfSomething` Component just like this:

```jsx
function withLastOfSomething(Component) {
  return function({something, ...otherProps}) {
    const item = something ? something[something.length - 1] : null;
    return <Component item={item} {...otherProps} />;
  }
}
```

Or with ES6 arrow functions, even more compactly like this:

```jsx
const withLastOfSomething = (Component) => ({something, ...otherProps}) => {
  const item = something ? something[something.length - 1] : null;
  return <Component item={item} {...otherProps} />;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```jsx
const SampleBWithLastOfSomething = withLastOfSomething(SampleB);

return (<SampleBWithLastOfSomething something={...} />);
```

Comment: thank you so much! so in my example, i shoule write the code "export default (<SampleBWithLastOfSomething something={...｝/>)" ?

Comment: One of the cool things with this pattern is that you can either apply it as a concept inherent to the component - in which case, yes, you'd do something like that - or as a concept inherent to the component's parent, in which case you'd just apply it upon rendering. Whichever makes the most sense for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the function that takes the passed props and executes the logic,

```
  export default renderLastItem = (passedProps) => {

    if(!passedProps) {
      return  null;
    }

    return passedProps [passedProps.length - 1]

  }
```

then import it wherever you need, like this:

```
import renderLastItem   from './somewhere'

export default class SampleA extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

        <div>
            <h1>Something</h1>
            <p>{renderLastItem(this.props.something)}</p>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```